# ACM reference format not show correctly

Tags: bibliographies, acmart

i'm using latex preparing paper. I use acm reference format (ACM-Reference-Format.bst) as reference style, it should produce something like this: [image]

but actually I get something like following:
 [image]

can anyone tells me how to create the first formatting style, or tell me which .bst file to use? thanks.
The code I use for citation:

```
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{reference}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you loaded the `natbib` citation management package?

Comment: not really, and I just tried \usepackage{natbib}, it changed the style but still not  the first style I want.

Comment: I don't really know what 'acm-reference-format.bst' should look like. I just want to produce the style in the first image.

Comment: I would like dispute your claim that `ACM-Reference-Format` bibliography style "... should produce something like this...". This bibliography style  definitely does not truncate first (given) names, and it doesn't place the truncated given names behind the surnames. Whoever told you that the first screenshot you posted was generated with the `ACM-Reference-Format` bib style was misinformed.

Comment: Incidentally, my preceding comments are based on the properties of the current version of `ACM-Reference-Format`, i.e., version 2.1., dated 14 June 2017. I have no idea if any substantive changes were made in version 2.1 regarding the way the `author` field is formatted; however, I would strongly doubt it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the [reference style sheet](http://www.sigplan.org/sites/default/files/acmart/current/ACM-Reference-Format.bst) in the same directory.